# mysql not starting up in ubuntu

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

I have installed mysql in ubuntu 12.04 LTS, When i try to start mysql it won't running up i tried lots of stack overflow answers. None of them worked ..

In one answers they told to upgrade, i did upgrade and now i have 14.04 LTS.

Still mysql not working..

Tried,[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13276088/cant-start-mysql5-5-on-ubuntu-12-04-dpkg-dependency-problems) and [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/455029/mysql-server-start-failed) also [this](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/mysqld-unrecognized-service-4175432133/)but wont helped.

```
mysql -u root -p
Enter password: 
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

help me to get out of this.

EDIT 1

```
/var/run/mysqld/ is empty directory
```

EDIT 2

```
service --status-all 

[?] mysql
```

Comment: can you paste what's there in `/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock`

Comment: check the services if mysql is properly installed. `service --status-all` . Tell us what symbol do you see beside mysql.

Comment: @EricT its [?] for mysql..

Comment: looks find, mine also `[?]`. Which do you install mysql-server or mysql-client?

Comment: installed mysql-server mysql-client