# Mysql install fails with dpkg: error processing package mysql-server-5.6 (--configure)

Tags: mysql, linux, installation, dpkg

This post isn't as long as it seems, most of it is quotes, don't panic!

I've got a totally fresh install of Elementary OS (Freya) and have successfully installed Apache2 and PHP 5.6. However the mysql install seems to fail. I'm a bit of a Linux idiot so apologies if i'm doing something stupid.

The error I receive is : `dpkg: error processing package mysql-server-5.6 (--configure)`

and here is the output from install:

> 2016-02-24 22:48:16 9597 [Note] InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 1625987
>   start: Job failed to start
>   invoke-rc.d: initscript mysql, action "start" failed.
>   dpkg: error processing package mysql-server-5.6 (--configure):
>    subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
>   Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.19-0ubuntu6.7) ...
>   Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-16) ...
>   Errors were encountered while processing:
>    mysql-server-5.6
>   E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

I have looked at various 'solutions' across forums and helpdesks and a lot of users have solved this by upping the RAM on their VM. I am **not** running a VM and my computer has 8GB RAM and 4GB swap.

Here are the necessary specs from my machine:

/ 18GB
/home 28GB
swap 4GB

and from free: (apologies for formatting!)

> ...............................total.........used........free.... shared.buffers...cached
>   .................. Mem:       8119632    2838764    5280868      21752     103068    1955740
>   -/+ buffers/cache:     779956    7339676
>   ..................Swap:      3905532          000000    3905532

I also tried the solution from this post:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/18456553/5000727

Sadly this also did not work.

I also edited the /etc/mysql/conf.d/mysql.cnf and added:

> [mysqld]
>     max_connections = 20

which was another suggestion, but nothing.

finally I tried the dpkg

> simon@simon-MS-7821:/$ sudo dpkg --configure -a
>   Setting up mysql-server-5.6 (5.6.28-0ubuntu0.14.04.1) ...
>   start: Job failed to start
>   invoke-rc.d: initscript mysql, action "start" failed.
>   dpkg: error processing package mysql-server-5.6 (--configure):
>    subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
>   Errors were encountered while processing:
>    mysql-server-5.6

I have absolutely no idea what to do any more it's driving me insane and I really need mysql! I hope one of you brilliant people out there may know how to fix this.

Many Thanks

Comment: No one :( aw damn it.

Comment: Hi Simon, Have you tried using strace to see where it's failing?

Answer (score 2):

I also faced this issue because my instance 512MB RAM. 
I upgrade my instance to 1GB RAM.
No more errors.

Comment: Yup, tried multiple droplets with different versions of ubantu. 1gb ram version worked for me for mysql, though i can install postgres on 512 ram instances.

Comment: Yup. This was the solution for DigitalOcean Ubuntu Droplet.

Answer (score 0):

Try first sudo dpkg --configure -a
Then try:
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade --fix-broken